# Most cost effective way to traverse a set path

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I have a set path of $N$ destinations to be visited in order, knowing the distance $D_i$ between each one of them. I can traverse one node $i$ with the cost of $D_i \times r$ or traverse any $5$ nodes in order with a set cost of $B$. How can I find the most cost effective way to visit all the destinations using dynamic programming?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify the problem statement.  Can you define more clearly what $D_i$ represents?  The distance between node $i$ and what?   What do you mean by "any 5 nodes in order"?  Can you credit where you encountered this and share the original wording?

Comment: What have you tried, and what progress have you made?  We have general resources on how to approach dynamic programming problems: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info.  I suggest you read through those resources, apply the systematic approach listed there, and show us how far you got.  Do you have a recursive algorithm?  What subproblem decompositions have you tried so far?

Comment: Is $r$ the same for every node or is it a variable? @BenedictDhm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us number the destinations from $1$ to $N$ and define an array $c[N]$ where $c[i]$ is the minimum cost to travel to destination $1 \leq i \leq N$. We wish to calculate $c[N]$.

It is clear that $c[1] = D_1 \times r$, because if we find ourselves at destination $1$ we can only have gotten there by travelling one destination at a time, instead of travelling five destinations at a time.

The minimum cost of travelling to destination $2$ must be $c[2] = D_2 \times r + c[1]$ for identical reasons ($2 < 5$) as before. We add the minimum cost of reaching destination $1$ to the minimum cost of reaching destination $2$ because we must have travelled from destination $1$ to $2$.

Now we see that for destinations $i \geq 5$, that we could have reached them by travelling through five destinations at a time instead of the previous one destination at a time. This means 
$$c[i] = \min(B + c[i - 5], D_{i} \times r + c[i - 1])$$

Where $c[0] = 0$. From this pattern, we can calculate $c[N]$ in $O(N)$ time complexity.